# how to access Configuration in a IWebHostBuilder extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As the topic says, I can't figure out how to access the Configuration object set up in CreateWebHostBuilder.

`Code`:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .CustomExtension();
```

In the code example I would like to access Configuration in the CustomExtension method

Answer (score 12):

For `IWebHostBuilder`, it is used to configure the `WebHost` pipeline.

For general way, if you want to access `Configuration`, you need to pass the `Configuration`  object to `CustomExtension` like :

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseConfiguration(config)
.UseKestrel()
.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

For another way, you could try like `UseConfiguration` to access `Configuration` object, but the code will run only when `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()` is called.

```
    public static class WebHostBuilderExtension
{
    public static IWebHostBuilder CustomExtension(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
    {
        return webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services => {
            var config = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var connection = config.GetConnectionString("Default");
        });
    }
    public static void CustomAction(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var config = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var connection = config.GetConnectionString("Default");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .CustomExtension()
            .ConfigureServices(services => WebHostBuilderExtension.CustomAction(services));
```

Comment: In my case ConfigureServices was being called too late, I had to call ConfigureAppConfiguration, for example `builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder config) => {var newConfiguration = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"test","false"}}; config.AddInMemoryCollection(newConfiguration); });`

Answer (score 0):

If need the configuration *before* build DI Container, you can use code like this:

```
public static class WebHostBuilderExtension
{
    private static IConfiguration _config;
    public static IWebHostBuilder CustomExtension(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
    {
        // 1 - Build and get configuration
        webHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
        {
            _config = conf.Build();
        });

        return webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services => {

            // 2 - Use configuration (before BuildServiceProvider)
            var connection = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            // some manipulation with services in DI container
            // ...
        });         
    }
}
```

And now use extension like this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .CustomExtension();
```